Clojure http classic web app don´t get access token on SSO authentication
I am building a simple http classic web application (request-response) in Clojure in orden to test the integration with Keycloak identity server.
I am ussing ring-oauth2 library, following the steps described in library documentation.
Here is the initialization of my app
(defn app-routes []
  (ring/router
   [["/"
     {:get {:handler (fn [request]
                       (response-handler request views/home-page))}}]]))

(defn wrap-site-defaults [handler]
  (ring.middleware.session/wrap-defaults handler (-> ring.middleware.defaults/site-defaults (assoc-in [:session :cookie-attrs :same-site] :lax)))

(defn wrap-oauth2-config [handler]
  (wrap-oauth2
   handler
   {:keycloak
    {:client-id "my-app"
     :client-secret "***********"
     :authorize-uri "http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth"
     :access-token-uri "http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token"
     :redirect-uri "http://localhost:3300/oauth2/callback"
     :scopes ["openid" "profile" "email"]
     :launch-uri "/login"
     :landing-uri "/"}}))

(defn -main []
  (let [handler (-> (ring/ring-handler (app-routes))
                    (wrap-oauth2-config) 
                    (wrap-site-defaults)
                    (ring.middleware.params/wrap-params))]
    (run-jetty handler {:port 3300 :join? false})
    (println "Server started on port 3300")))

After run the app and git the endpoint http://localhost:3300/login the authenticate process is completed in Keycloak but after the redirection to home page the key :oauth2/access-tokens is not present in the request.
What mistake could I be making?
Am I missing some configuration, middleware?
Is the order in which I have the middlewares correct?

After a lot of tests and find a great repo as example (Booklog) i fix my problem
First:
Use only ["profile" "email"] scopes inside oauth2 configuration
Second:
Use "/oauth2/done" as landing-uri instead of "/". With this I have managed to decode the access token and build an identity key (:identity) and associate it with the current session.
Third:
correct the order of middlewares
Aquí comparto como ha quedado mi código
(defn app-routes []
  (ring/router
   [["/"
     {:get {:handler (fn [request]
                       (response-handler request views/home-page))}}]
    ["/oauth2/done"
     {:get {:handler (fn [request]
                       (let [identity (fetch-identity (get-in request [:oauth2/access-tokens :keycloak :token]))
                             next-session (assoc (:session request) :identity identity)]
                         (-> (redirect "/")
                             (assoc :session next-session))))}}] 
    ["/logout"
     {:get {:handler (fn [_]
                       {:status 302
                        :headers {"Location" "http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/logout?client_id=my-clientb&post_logout_redirect_uri=http://localhost:3300"}
                        :session nil})}}]]))

(defn wrap-oauth2-config [handler]
  (wrap-oauth2
   handler
   {:keycloak
    {:client-id "my-client"
     :client-secret "************"
     :authorize-uri "http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth"
     :access-token-uri "http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token"
     :redirect-uri "http://localhost:3300/oauth2/callback"
     :scopes ["profile" "email"]
     :basic-auth? true
     :launch-uri "/login"
     :landing-uri "/oauth2/done"}}))

(defn -main []
  (let [handler (-> (ring/ring-handler (app-routes))
                    (wrap-authentication (backends/session))
                    (wrap-session)
                    (auth/wrap-oauth2-config)
                    (wrap-defaults (-> site-defaults 
                                       (assoc-in [:session :cookie-attrs :same-site] 
                                                 :lax))))]
    (run-jetty handler {:port 3300 :join? false})
    (println "Server started on port 3300")))

